# Use of どうも　in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 彼は、どうも彼女に会いにこの展望台を訪れているようです

It seems that he visited the lookout to meet her

In terms of どうも, the person in question has already visited her several times and there really isn't much difficulty in doing so. So the somehow/no matter what definition is hard to apply here.

thank you

Comment: One definition seems to be really, so: "It seems like he *really* visits the lookout to meet her" (as opposed to some stated reason for visiting the lookout)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That どうも or どうやら are a kind of adverbs called 呼応の副詞 (guiding adverb), which alone doesn't really work but leads a certain type of predicates according to each word, in this case, conjecture through observation like …ようだ or …らしい.

Even without どうも, the meaning of the sentence doesn't change.

もし, なぜなら, 決して or so are this kind too.