# Does あたかも only add emphasis to a sentence?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

Does あたかも only add emphasis, without introducing any new meaning to a sentence? Would the sentence mean the same without it? It's translated as [**as if**](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%82%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%82), but most [sentences I find it used with](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%82%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%82%20%23sentences) already use よう（に）, which expresses such meaning already (as far as I'm aware):

> 彼女【かのじょ】は**あたかも**幽霊【ゆうれい】でも見【み】たかの**ように**見【み】えた。

> 彼【かれ】らは**あたかも**蟻【あり】の**ように**働【はたら】いた。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

あたかも has two meanings. As [naruto](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/5010/naruto) mentions, when あたかも is used to mean `as if`, it's very rarely used without ごとく or ように. But it does sometimes happen. My examples are pulled from the [corpus provided by The National Institute for Japanese Language and Linguistics](http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/headword/AV.00266/)

> - しかも、青ナイルのおかげで、この土地の耕作地には、自動的に養分が供給される。 **あたかも**天然の肥料自動供給装置を備えていると言ってもよい。
> - 夢心地の来園者の前には、すかさず気持ちを捉えるグッズの数々を揃えた店が並ぶ。 理想の楽園は、言葉を替えれば**あたかも**一個の巨大なマーケット。
> - この嫉妬心は宇宙の法則として与えられているかぎり、これを取り除くことはできません。 **あたかも**、万有引力をなくすることができないのと同じであります。

However, when it's used to mean ちょうどその時, it doesn't use ように at all. It's most often combined with a 時 before it. Here are some examples:

> - その製品が誕生したのは、時**あたかも**太平洋戦争の最中であった。
> - 私が生まれたのは、時**あたかも**年号が平成に変わった年でした
> - これは一九四九年五月のアチソン国務長官の言葉である。 とき**あたかも**中国大陸で共産党軍が勝利していた時期であった。

Answer (score 2):

あたかも is a guiding adverb which is almost always used with ようだ. (This is unlike まるで, which can be used without ようだ.) あたかも emphasizes the sentence, but does nothing to the basic meaning of the sentence. Other guiding adverbs include [もし](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62037/5010) and [どうも](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50203/5010).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Sometimes, あたかも is used as “just when”([https://www.weblio.jp/content/あたかも#KNJJN](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%82%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%82#KNJJN)). From this, you will see あたかも functions as an emphasis. But usually, あたかも and 〜のように is a set phrase. It is the same as まるで〜のように. And it’s okay without あたかも.